# PDO dynamic Table column name

Tags: php, html-table

I want to create table with PHP. I need to get the name of all column dynamically.

Something like this:

```
id  name  username  email
 .   .       .        .
 .   .       .        . 
 .   .       .        .
 .   .       .        .
```

My code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $connection -> prepare($query);
$result -> execute();

echo "<table border=1 width=100%>";
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<th>$key</th>";
}
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($result -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $value)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>".$value -> id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value-> name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value-> username."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value -> password."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$value -> account."</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
    echo '</table>';
```

But I lose my first record in second foreach loop, when I fetch my all records.
In fact my first record is `$value` in the first foreach loop.I want to set that in TD tags, in the second foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try caching the results.***

The problem you are having is `->fetch` doesn't just grab the keys of the table - it grabs the first row AND the keys.

### The following code should work for you :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = $connection -> prepare($query);
$result -> execute();

// store results in memory
$headers = '<tr>';
$output = '<tr>';
foreach( $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $key=>$value ) {
    $headers .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
    $output .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
$headers .= '</tr>';
$output .= '</tr>';

foreach ($result -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $value)
{
    $output .= '<tr>'
            . '<td>' . $value->id . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $value->name . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $value->username . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $value->password . '</td>'
            . '<td>' . $value->account . '</td>'
            . '</tr>';
}
$output = '<table border="1" width="100%">' . $output . '</table>';

// output result set (full table)
echo $output;
```

The above example takes all the result set and builds the table on the fly. Since it is storing to memory, this also has the advantage of processing much faster over `echo` on each partial html element. It outputs the table once it has finished building in a single echo.